# Dealing with table on page breaks when printing

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm printing a lot of big tables, and every single one of them has a margin-top to separate them. It works well but when a table breaks between pages, so the next one doesn't print with the margin at the top.

It looks like this
[image]